# Addition of arrays in a function

Tags: arrays, c, sum, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Here is where the problems begins when i try to write the arrays within the function

```
 int suma(int a[i], int b[i], int i){


    return a[n] + b[n];

}


void main(void){

int i,n,num;


do{
      printf("Ingrese el tamaño de los vectores: ");
      scanf("%i",&n);
        if (n>50){
             printf("Ingrese el tamaño de los vectores: ");
             scanf("%i",&n);
             num==0;
        }

        else if (n<=50){

            num++;
        }

}while (num==0);

int vec1[n], vec2[n],vec3[n];

for (i=0;i<n;i++){

    printf("Introduce los valores para el primer vector: \n");
    scanf("%i",&vec1[i]);

}

for (i=0;i<n;i++){

    printf("Introduce los valores para el segundo vector: \n");
    scanf("%i",&vec2[i]);

}

    printf("La suma de los dos vectore es: \n");

    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
```

Here should be the vec3[i]=vec1[i]+vec2[i] but i need to do it with a function

```
    vec3[i]=suma(vec1[i],vec2[i]); 

    printf("Posicion %d -->%i\n",i,vec3[i]);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays do not have the assignment operator.

It seems what you need is the following.

```
void suma( int a1[], const int a2[], const int a3[], int n )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        a1[i] = a2[i] + a3[i];
    }
}
```

And call this function before the loop that outputs the result array like

```
suma( vec3, vec1, vec2, n );
```

and then

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("Posicion %d -->%i\n",i,vec3[i]);
}
```

Comment: really really aprecciate your help, thank you very much